# Web API multiple get

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have couple of get methods in my web API class. The route config is as below;

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "CustomApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/test/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "item", action="testBring", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The controller class is as below;

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Item
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        [ActionName("testBring")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string testBring()
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // GET: api/Item/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Item
        [HttpPost]
        public void CreateItem([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/Item/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Item/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

When I try to call */api/test*, **testBring** method gets called. But when I call */api/Item* I get an error that **multiple actions were found that match the request ...** Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

`/api/test` maps fine to the first route template `api/test/{action}/{id}` because of the default parameters included, which allow it to call a specific action.

However, `/api/Item` maps to the second route template `api/{controller}/{id}` and the route table is unable to determine which action you wanted since there are multiple `HttpGet` actions (ie `Get()` and `testBring()` ) that match the requested path.

Comment: But why doesn't  [ActionName("testBring")] gets matched?